# Why do I have grey inside my div

Tags: html, css

I'm looking at my div named 'mainsearchsection' and I see a small amount of grey above and to the left of each of my search fields. I'm not sure why? Is there something messed up about the margins or padding?

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/XLhsR/

```
<div class="mainsearchsection">
        <h1>Share gifts with friends.</h1>
        <h2>Services to exchange from every country.</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Gifts", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <div class="mainsearchdiv">
                <input class="mainsearch" type='search' name='searchTerm' value='Gifts' data-ouluvu-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutoComplete")" />
                <input class="mainlocation" type="text" name="location" value="Location" />
                <input class="mainavailability" type="text" name="availability" value="Availability" />
                <input class="mainsubmit" type='submit' value='Search' />
            </div>
        }
    </div>


.mainsearchdiv {
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
background-color: black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainsearch {
width: 300px;
height: 35px;
margin-left: 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainsubmit {
height: 35px;
width: 80px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainlocation {
height: 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainavailability {
height: 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, text inputs have a border, and that's what you're seeing here. To turn that off, do this

```
.mainsearchsection input {
    border-width:0;
}
```

See more: http://jsfiddle.net/XLhsR/4/

Answer (score 3):

Browsers automatically add a border to input fields. Try using a reset stylesheet or use

```
input {
 border: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XLhsR/1/